# how do i integrate ccavenue payment gateway in my android app

Tags: android, payment-gateway, ccavenue

am new in android ,i want to know about how to integrate cc-avenue payment gateway mobile checkout page in my android application ,where i want the user should fill his card details and pay on-line ,hope i will get something out from here ...thanks in advance

Comment: Follow the intraction in following pdf http://world.ccavenue.com/downloads/CCAVenueWorldIntegrationManual.pdf

Comment: This is fine but i don't get anything for android /mobile from here

Comment: Have you get answer of your question??

Comment: 1.4k views..but off-topic...gr8

Comment: You need to register for their service. after validation of required documents they provide you the android integration api and guide to set up payment gateway.

Comment: Did any one get solution for this?

Comment: Hi,, Did you find out the solution

Comment: After transaction not getting response but it showing processing page in android mobile integration with ccavenue non-seamless . some one help me pls.

Comment: @satyapol  "after validation of required documents" what are those documents i am not getting activation mail

Comment: @Shubham You should call the customer care no. They need the proof of firm registration and few required links on the website where you're going to integrate the API. If you're going to use it in app then you should specify them about purpose specifically.

Comment: can anyone share sample code for ccavenue android ios